# json not validating because of apostrophe 's

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I have a json string

```
'{\'category\':{\'id\': 123, \'place\': "Brazil\'s Beech"}}'
```

and I am trying to convert it to python dictionary object but couldn't make it.

I have tried replacing `"\'"` with `"\""` but the problem is `'s` in `"Brazil\'s Beech"`

because of this apostrophe also get replaced with double quote and the json becomes invalid.

Answer (score 0):

First of all it's not valide JSON format since variables are not in double quotes.

However you can use triple quoted string and eval to make it to a dict.

```
>>> k = """{'category':{'id': 123, 'place': "Brazil's Beech"}}"""
>>> eval(k)

{'category': {'id': 123, 'place': "Brazil's Beech"}}

>>> type(eval(k))
dict
```

This would be a valid JSON String

```
>>> js = json.dumps(eval(k))
>>> js
'{"category": {"id": 123, "place": "Brazil\'s Beech"}}'
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, it works but I am not sure if this is correct way of solving this problem.. looking something like `json.loads`

Comment: Where and how do you get the JSON. What you are calling as JSON isn't actually properly formatted JSON